# Should you be able to declare two private variables in differnet files with the same name?

Tags: swift

In Swift, it is a compile error to do this:

```
// file1.swift

private let testVar = 2

// file2.swift

private let testVar = 3
```

In particular, one of the declarations will be highlighted with 'Invalid redeclaration of testVar'.

---

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html) states, in general, that:

> Private access restricts the use of an entity to its own defining source file. Use private access to hide the implementation details of a specific piece of functionality.

When discussing raw values, it says:

> The types used for any raw values or associated values in an enumeration definition must have an access level at least as high as the enumeration’s access level. You cannot use a private type as the raw value type of an enumeration with an internal access level, for example.

And with respect to constants:

> A constant, variable, or property cannot be more public than its type. It is not valid to write a public property with a private type, for example. Similarly, a subscript cannot be more public than either its index type or return type.

---

To me, none of those extracts suggest that you should not be able to have `private` variables with the same name in separate files.

Indeed, the first quote says to me that you *should* be able to; otherwise, you're leaking implementation details (ie, the fact that you used a variable named `testVar`).

---

Before I file a bug report, I wanted to check that I'm not misunderstanding the semantics.
Should this be possible?

Comment: Seems that this shroud not be allowed. Just being in a different file is insufficient. Think about link-time.

Comment: @Zaph I assumed it would work in the same way as static variables in C (ie, not exposed to the linker).  It seems odd that you could break your build just by adding a new file to a project!

Comment: I guess it comes down to how private is handled. File a bug and see what the response is.

Comment: My bug report was marked as a duplicate of #17632175, which appears not to be public.  I guess that means we'll see a fix in due course.

Comment: Bug reports are private because many times it is necessary to include information that is private. That there is another bug report does not mean that there will be a "fix" soon or ever.

Comment: This is now listed as a known issue in the GM build: 'Private entities with the same name and same type will conflict even if defined in different files within the same module. (17632175)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in Xcode 6.1 beta 2:

> **Issues Resolved in Xcode 6.1 Beta**
>
> **Swift Language**
>
> Private entities with the same name and same type will no longer conflict if defined in different files within the same module. (17632175)

Answer (score 0):

The swift documentation states:

> By default, variables, constants, and other named declarations that are declared at the top-level of a source file are accessible to code in every source file that is part of the same module.

You would need to have your files in a different module or else scope the variables within a class.

Comment: But it *also* states that `Private access restricts the use of an entity to its own defining source file`, and normally the specific would override the general as a matter of construction, especially where what you've posted is expressed as a default rule.